# Fit a VAR model with R

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

I have a bivariate time series `z_t` where `z_1t` is the change in monthly US treasury bills (maturity 3 months) and `z_2t` the inflation rate, in percentage, of the U.S. monthly consumer price index (CPI). CPI used is the consumer price index for all urban consumers: all items (CPIAUCSL). The original data are downloaded from the Federal Reserve Bank of St.Louis. The CPI rate is 100 times the first difference of the log CPI index. I want to fit the specified VAR model and simplify the fit by a command R (`refVar` from package `MTS` or `restrict` from package `vars`) with threshold 1.65.

I found this exercise ([pdf](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2013/hw3-13.pdf)) on R. Tsay's website at the University of Chicago.  The data are [here](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2013/m-cpitb3m.txt).

What I did until now is the following:

```
y <- diff(zt[,3])
lot(y, type="l", ylab="tb3m")

 # difference 
x <- diff(log(zt[,4]))
plot(x, type="l", ylab="CPI rate")

new <- cbind(x, y)
 # order selection gives VAR(6)
VARselect(new, lag.max=9, type="const")

data1 <- data[,c("tb3m","cpiaucsl")]
fit   <- VAR(data1,p=6)
fit

restrict(fit, method="ser", thresh=1.65, resmat=T)
```

`restrict` and `VAR` don't give me the right results or the same coefficients of the Var model in the answers in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

After you fit your model using:

```
fit <- VAR(data1,p=6)
```

You can refine it with `refVAR`:

```
fit2 <- refVAR(fit,thres=1.65)
```

Comment: Welcome to CV and many thanks for your first contribution. I've made some small edits (so too has @gung) where I removed the greeting and signature. More information about answering questions can be found at the help centre (http://stats.stackexchange.com/help) and in reference to greetings and signatures, see here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behaviour. Again, welcome along to CV! :)

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little, such as explaining what `refVAR` does?